# JS JQ Resizable do not resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, resizable

I have cut html part of page and put script and css from code below: [FULL EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/a7hC4/)
In the example grey bottom line is working, it's resizing. But in the page is not. What can go wrong there?
JS:

```
    $(function() {
    $( ".stopResizingItemsOfSplashScreen" ).resizable({
        handles: {
            's': '.bottomBorderOfItemsSplashScreen'
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Do you have any errors in browser console ?

Comment: No, there is none. I think is something from css side. Something that override possition or something else, but i cant figure it out.

Comment: It will be hard to find answer without seeing code of whole page.

Comment: Is there any tool that can compare two console?